# UnicodeDecodeError is showing on the window ........... how to solve it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

[image]

i am simply reading from one file but why this is showing error? how to get rid of it?

Comment: Google "python docx UnicodeDecodeError" and you can find some other similar questions

Comment: Please post the code and error as text instead of a screenshot. its easier to read, we can copy / paste examples and questions look more uniform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi docx is a special extension that has been built by Microsoft normal python `with open` only supports RAW data files such as .csv .txt etc. Use [docx](https://pypi.org/project/docx/) library to read a docx file [example](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/documents.html) as below.

```
import docx

# open connection to Word Document
doc = docx.Document("zen_of_python.docx")

# read in each paragraph in file
result = [p.text for p in doc.paragraphs]
```

Comment: now it is showing ModuleNotFoundError

Comment: install the required library from the given link that library link is hyperlinked in docx in the answer.